# How to write logs to file in order

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have a concurrency hashmap, I want to record each operation that modify the hashmap in the same file.
And then three workers thread(for example A,B,C) can be access to the hashmap and the log file, an id generator will generate id for each task received by the workers.

for example:

```
workers:  A  B  C
tasks:    a  b  c
ids:      1  2  3
completed orders:c b a
```

workers:A,  B,  C received three tasks: a, b, c in order. The ids of a,b, c are 1,2,3. However, it's possible that the tasks completed in the order of c,b,a and then write to the log file in the wrong order.Of course, I can refuse to write the log to the file if id of completed task is smaller than the biggest id recored ever, but the hashmap has been changed.So What should I do to ensure they
are recorded in order.

Comment: Detach the log writing from your worker thread, since you care about the job's order of issue rather than their order of completion. Make a queue of jobs in issue order, have the worker threads update job status in the queue, and write the log file when all jobs ended.

Comment: it seem that this approach  does not work, because server will receive the request from client continusously, you have no idea when all of these tasks are done or never all of these tasks are done.I guess I need to implement the transaction like databases